# Arduino : How to Print Data (character) From Serial on LCD Screen?

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I have 2 Serials in Arduino

**Serial** = To print data string in serial (dataRaspi)

**Serial1** = To read the datas from "Serial1" and print this out on LCD Screen.

Here is my Code

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(52, 50, 48, 46, 44, 42);

int byteRead;

void setup() 
{  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600); //INTIALISING THE SERIAL PORT
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop()
{
**this is listing to print data string to Serial** 
dataRaspi = "$" + data_yaw + "|" + data_pitch + "|" + data_roll + "|" + data_lat + "|" + data_lon + "|" + data_airSpd + "|" + data_alt_qnh + "#";

Serial.println(dataRaspi);
delay(1);

**this is listing to read data from Serial1**
if(Serial1.available())
{
   while(Serial1.available < 0)
   byteRead = Serial1.read;
   lcd.print(byteRead);
}
```

**The Question is...**

**my lcd got blank if i give a series of string input to serial1 like "qwerty". How to display the result from serial1 to my lcd display?**

Answer (score 2):

Your code has :    "while(Serial1.available < 0)", ie while available bytes less than 0... , also, the while statement will only control the single following statement... you need:

```
while (Serial1.available()) {
    lcd.print(Serial1.read());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure the display initialisation is Ok. So, comment out the serial read block and try printing a hardcoded string on the display.

[Here](https://www.makerguides.com/character-lcd-arduino-tutorial/) is an examle on **how to use** 16x2 lcd.

If you find out there is no initialisation problem you can continue with improving your serial read code. In the arduino forum there is a very good [topic on serial communication basics](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=288234.0) by Robin2.

When you need to constantly update printed data on any display you need a string which is almost similar to the currently printed one or else it will flicker all the time and you won't see anything.

**example (pseudocode):**
print "clock: 10:31"
print "clock: 10:32"
print "clock: 10:33"
etc.

This way only the time would change without the "clock" string. If you need to print strings that have nothing in common just add **delay(ms)** between the **lcd.print()** lines in order the change of the strings to be visible.

I hope that was useful in some way. Keep learning.